# Compatibility issue with google-cloud-language in Cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-language

I'm using the python3 API `google-cloud-language 1.3.0` in `composer-1.8.3-airflow-1.10.3`.

It used to be well but from last two weeks it reported **ImportError: cannot import name 'aio' from 'grpc.experimental'**

I've checked the doc of package, it looks like `google-cloud-language` now requires `grpcio>=1.29.0`. However according to Cloud Composer version list, even for the lastest version of composer its PyPI package grpcio stays on `1.23.0`

I tried to force its version up to `1.29.0` but failed.

Does anyone can check this issus?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully upgrade the `grpcio` library version to `1.31.0`. As a first step I would suggest you to upgrade your Cloud Composer instance to the most current version(`composer-1.11.3-airflow-1.10.9`), since it should be more stable and solved some issues.

To install the newer version of PyPi package in Cloud Composer, you can follow these steps or [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package):

1. Create the `requirements.txt` file and pass the package name with version:

```
grpcio>=1.29.0
```

2. Execute the update command with providing the ENVIRONMENT_NAME, full path to the newly created file and LOCATION of the Composer environment (i.e. europe-west1).

```
gcloud composer environments update <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> \\
--update-pypi-packages-from-file </PATH/requirements.txt> \\
--location <LOCATION>
```

The steps that I have taken to confirm that `grpcio` version has changed from `1.23.0` to `1.31.0` are following:

1. [Connect to the GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver#connect-cluster) for your environment by executing following command in Cloud Shell. You can find the `GKE_CLUSTER` value within your environment in `ENVIRONMENT CONFIGURATION` -> `GKE cluster` variable. `GKE_LOCATION` replace with the zone name:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${GKE_CLUSTER} --zone ${GKE_LOCATION}
```

2. Connect to the worker POD in the GKE cluster. The NAMESPACE name should start with: `composer-<version>-...`, and POD_NAME with: `airflow-worker-...`:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
kubectl exec -itn <NAMESPACE_NAME> <POD_NAME>  -- /bin/bash
```

3. Run pip freeze to see all packages installed in the environemnt with corresponding version:

```
pip freeze
```

4. Look for `grpcio==1.31.0` package.

**Update:**

When you try to install the new packages Composer tries to create a new build, but it fails, this can be seen in the logs for Cloud Build by using the following advanced filter in Stackdriver Logging:

```
resource.type="build"
```

The problem is conflicting PyPi dependencies, each update operation triggers a Cloud Build operation that rebuilds images.  In the version of Composer that you are using Cloud Build failed the update operation when saw any conflict. In the newest version `1.11.3` you will be able to choose if you want to allow conflicts or not.

Based on this, I would share two recommendations to avoid the issue you are experiencing:

- Create a new environment with a more recent Composer version or [upgrading](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading) the existing one. In more recent versions (>=1.10.0) Composer use pip in version `19.0.2` instead of `9.0.3`. Therefore pip itself may be finding dependencies better.
- Analyse Cloud Build logs and pin the packages to versions that are not conflicting; however, this maybe quite difficult because once you resolve one conflict the other conflict could appear.

Comment: Hi Ines, TXS for the ansmer. I've tried this way but it still failed and showed _An error occurred before the new web server image has been created._ Do you have any idea about this message? Is it caused by the version of composer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and providing me with the error message you are facing. I've updated my answer with relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is still useful. I encountered the same problem and it was solved by upgrading `grpcio` to the latest version(my current is 1.27).

At the moment, it is

```
pip install grpcio==1.51.1
```